# Command prompt launches "java.exe" with .exe extension, but not without .exe extension

Tags: windows-7

I faced an issue today when running apps on windows using the cmd prompt. When I try to run a program I should add the extension at the end of the program name so it can be recognized by cmd.

For example, when I run "java -version" I get the following error : **'Java' is not recognized as an internal or external command**

But when I add .exe to the program "java.exe -version", I get the version of java installed on my computer.

Is there any solution to this problem as a lot of other programs relies on java command without the exe extension.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This has to do with your systme variables. Have you tried to simply reinstall Java?  I have confirmed it should simply work, which means, your system configuration is to blame.

Comment: This is a problem with all commands like java, ftp, cmd,...

Comment: Type `where java` and `where java.exe` and show us the results. This is going to be a `PATH` issue or a `PATHEXT` issue, I think.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I have to type .exe after all commands in windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1079605/why-do-i-have-to-type-exe-after-all-commands-in-windows-10)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The path was well defined. I solved my problem by adding .EXE to the PATHEXT environment variable.

Thanks a lot guys for your answers

Comment: Odd...usually .EXE is included in PATHEXT by default. Any idea why/how it was removed?

Comment: Maybe because I installed python(x,y) and it removed it (I found only .py and .pyc in the PATHEXT variable) or maybe it is due to a virus.

Comment: Confirming re PythonXY wiping the USER PATHEXT contents. I used to have .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC, and ended up with .PY;.PYW The remedy is in editing it to include .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.PYW

Answer (score 2):

This issue also happens if your user `PATHEXT` variable overrides the system `PATHEXT` variable, without extending the system `PATHEXT` variable

Prefix the `%PATHEXT%` variable in your user `PATHEXT` variable to solve this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer was correct (`PATHEXT` issue).
In case anyone else runs into this, in my case (Windows 8.1), the `PATHEXT` was like this:

```
.COM; .EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
```

In other words, there was a space before the .EXE and the extension was not recognized. Removing the space helped, so now I can run the `java -version` again.