# What would cause an EXE extension to be mandatory at the command line and how can it be resolved in the current shell?

Tags: windows-7, windows, cmd.exe

What would cause an EXE extension to be mandatory at the command line and how can it be resolved in the current shell?

I had a path that was long. > 2048 characters, and I installed a program, nodejs that added to that path. And then things went a bit screwy. I had a problem that some people seem to get at some point when their path is > 2048 char. The bulk of my path got removed. (I still have some old cmd shells with my path so that's not a big problem so i've saved my old path in a file)   And the windir environment variable got (I think set to nothing), in the registry. And I couldn't even open the environment variables window (this is a symptom people can get when their path is > 2048 char and they lose their windir variable).  So I used setx to create `windir=c:\windows` and I opened the environment variables window and fixed my PATH to what it was. And now cmd prompt windows that I open are fine.

But I still have some older cmd prompt windows from prior to me fixing it, and I understand the path is shortened in them, and I understand there's no windir variable set, but I still see a bizarre result in them that I cannot explain. And that i'd like to be able to fix from within those cmd windows.

It seems that I need to put the EXE after an executable in order to run it.

```
C:\crp>path
PATH=C:\Ruby21\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IDM Computer Solutions\UltraEdit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\IDM Computer Solutions\UltraCompare\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap;C:\Program Files (x86)\smartmontools\bin;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Users\user\AppData
\Roaming\npm

C:\crp>cd \windows\system32

C:\Windows\System32>ping
'ping' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Windows\System32>ping.exe

Usage: ping [-t] [-a] [-n count] [-l size] [-f] [-i TTL] [-v TOS]
......


C:\Windows\System32>set path=

C:\Windows\System32>ping.exe

Usage: ping [-t] [-a] [-n count] [-l size] [-f] [-i TTL] [-v TOS]
.....

C:\Windows\System32>ping
'ping' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Windows\System32>
```

and

```
C:\Windows\System32>ping
'ping' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Windows\System32>set windir=c:\windows

C:\Windows\System32>echo %windir%
c:\windows

C:\Windows\System32>ping
'ping' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Windows\System32>ping.exe

Usage: ping [-t] [-a] [-n count] [-l size] [-f] [-i TTL] [-v TOS]
```

The funny thing is that I think what solved it for future cmd prompts was setting windir permanently, i.e. with setx (then ( went to environemnt variables window and fixed the path).

I could fix the path within a busted cmd session, I can even fix windir in that cmd session, I know doing neither should help but it's making putting EXE at the end of filenames mandatory. So I don't see the cause.. or how to fix it for a particular cmd session.

New cmd windows are fine.. But for the sake of understand what is going on, I want to be able to fix it from within a busted cmd session. And if not, then i'd like to know why it can't be fixed within it.

**Added**

Relevant to  Dmitry's post

```
C:\Windows\System32>echo %PATHEXT%
%PATHEXT%;.RB;.RBW
```

Indeed, I see .EXE is not listed, and a bit odd that literal %PATHEXT% is listed in there. Seems almost infinitely recursive(if DOS were to even handle recursion / recursion there, which it wouldn't)!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command prompt launches "java.exe" with .exe extension, but not without .exe extension](https://superuser.com/questions/675006/command-prompt-launches-java-exe-with-exe-extension-but-not-without-exe-ext)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you check `PATHEXT` environment variable?  It lists extensions, considered executable.  Mine is like this:

```
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.LNK;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.AU3
```

BTW, there's nice environment editor: [Rapid Environment Editor](http://www.rapidee.com/en/about)

Comment: That was it. PATHEXT didn't have .EXE listed there. And it was even corrupted into having literal %PATHEXT% in there.  That must have somehow fixed itself for later cmd prompts, during the process after when I did setx to set windir, and was then able to get the properties environment variables window open and added the path variable in propertly and hit OK.