# PATHEXT environment variable not working

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, environment-variables

I want to use gcc on Windows, so someone gave me a MinGW folder. I put the `D:\software\MinGW\bin\` folder in my PATH. But when I open a new CMD and type `gcc`, I get

> 'gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

However, when I type `gcc.exe`, it works.

So I read on [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1079605/why-do-i-have-to-type-exe-after-all-commands-in-windows-10) that this may be related to my PATHEXT variable. However, I changed my PATHEXT system variable so that it matches exactly what is said in the answer, and I removed my PATHEXT user variable, but it didn't change anything, I still have to write `gcc.exe` instead of `gcc`.

The strange thing is, other programs like Java work without writing the `.exe` extension. It seems like this problem only impacts the executables inside the `D:\software\MinGW\bin\` folder.

```
D:\> set PATH
```

> Path=D:\software\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files\Python39\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Python39;D:\software\Perl64\bin;C:\Users\Jacopo\AppData\Roaming\ActiveState\bin;D:\software\VMWare\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;D:\software\Node;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;D:\software\doxygen\bin;C:\xampp\mysql\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Gpg4win..\GnuPG\bin;D:\software\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit;D:\software\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64;D:\software\OpenSSL-Win64\bin;D:\software\Nmap;D:\software\Aliases;D:\software\MinGW\bin;D:\software\Ruby27-x64\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;D:\software\Git\cmd;D:\software\Node;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java;D:\software\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin;D:\software\Qt\5.9.8\winrt_x86_msvc2917\bin;C:\Users\Jacopo\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;D:\software\Docker Toolbox;D:\software\Nmap;

> PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC

What did I do wrong?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the current contents of your PATH variable within the body of your question.  You need to attempt running the command within a MinGW prompt.  While it is possible to run gcc without MinGW your system isn't configured to do that (i.e. WSL).

Comment: @Ramhound Done.

Comment: I also had the same problem, and I fixed it by simply making all the extensions lowercase (though I don't know why that worked, I though Windows was case-insensitive).

Comment: This could happen if you have set the drive to be case-sensitive

Comment: You can check this by running command `fsutil.exe file queryCaseSensitiveInfo C:\path\to\dir`

Answer (score 0):

The one explanation I can come up with for this behavior is that you have a file
or folder in the `MinGW\bin` folder that is named `gcc`.

This would require to add `.exe` to avoid using that file.

Check for the existence of `gcc` in `MinGW\bin` or any of its sub-folders.

Comment: There is no such file in the folder, but would it be possible that the error was caused by a `gcc` file in another folder of the Path? In doubt, I removed `D:\software\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin` and `D:\software\Qt\5.9.8\winrt_x86_msvc2917\bin` from my Path but nothing changed. I should add that on Powershell it works without specifying the `.exe`.

Comment: A fast check is in CMD to `set PATHEXT=.EXE` and try.

Comment: No, nothing changed unfortunately.

Comment: Check both versions of PATHEXT - user and system. One might be overriding the other.

Comment: I deleted the user PATHEXT. The one you see at the end of the `set PATH` result is the system one

Comment: From your description, PATHEXT seems not to be working, forcing you to fully specify the extension. Try the [where command](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html) in CMD : `where gcc` and `where gcc.exe`. Is this happening for other commands than `gcc`?

Comment: `where gcc` and `where gcc.exe` both return `D:\software\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe`. This problem happens for every executable inside the `D:\software\MinGW\bin\` folder.

Comment: Weird. Try to boot in Safe mode to check if some installed application is interfering.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by copying my `MinGW` folder from the `D:\` drive to the `Program File` folder on the `C:\` drive. I changed the `Path` variable accordingly, and it worked. Still no idea why it didn't work with the `D:\software` folder.