# Why does a file get opened when I write its name, without extensions, in the command line?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

On Windows 10, I have a file called `truffle.js` in my current folder.
I write `truffle` in the cmd window, expecting to invoke the `truffle` program which resides elsewhere on my path.

Instead, `truffle.js` is opened in my favorite IDE (`.js` files are associated with that IDE). I thought this behavior is only like this for executable files, `.bat`, `.com` and `.exe`. Why does it happen for a `.js` file?

Note: I subsequently discovered I have no `truffle` at all installed on my path, but my question remains: why is Windows completing the extension which I did not specify on a non-executable file?

Even after installing truffle and restarting cmd, I can't get the real truffle to run in a folder that contains a file `truffle.js`.

Comment: [Server 2008 won't run executables from CMD prompt without .exe extension](https://serverfault.com/q/245751/343888)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command prompt launches "java.exe" with .exe extension, but not without .exe extension](https://superuser.com/questions/675006/command-prompt-launches-java-exe-with-exe-extension-but-not-without-exe-ext)

Comment: Because Windows will open any file with extensions that have an associated application.  It's saving you from having to type `c:\path\application.exe c:\path\filename.ext` rather than just `filename`.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Because `%PATHEXT%` is set to `.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC` by default. Note how it contains `.js`.

That means if you type a name, CMD will look for files with these extensions appended, in that order, in the current folder. Only after that will it consider what’s in `%PATH%`. This behavior cannot be changed. You can modify `%PATHEXT%` though, like any other environment variable.

You can use the `WHERE` command to check which path would be opened (e.g. `where truffle`), which will automatically search both %PATH% and %PATHEXT% the same way CMD would.

Comment: To clarify, you mean that windows will take an input, add those file extensions to the input to see if it matches, before looking in the PATH.

Comment: Also note that OP's original logic holds - these are all executables (in some sense of the word...), some of them just happen to also be human readable.

Comment: @TankorSmash Yes. It’ll probably do the same with every entry in `%PATH%`, though I haven’t tried. That all only applies to Command Prompt though.

Comment: @TankorSmash Windows, as in the `CreateProcess` and I think also the `ShellExecute(Ex)` APIs, doesn't look at PATHEXT. The extension search is only implemented within the default shells (cmd.exe and powershell.exe). That said, `CreateProcess` and `ShellExecute(Ex)` *will* append `.exe` specifically.

Comment: PowerShell only runs the file if you really specify a path: `my-file` and `my-file.js` will result in an error message while `.\my-file` will invoke the default action. In my case the default action is in fact Notepad++ and not execution.

Comment: @Adonalsium In fact, most of those are specifically executable scripts - only `com` and `exe` are "binary executables", while `vbe` and `jse` are encoded VB and JS scripts respectively. `msc` is management snap-in - again mostly for administration. It's just that there's other uses for `js` and `vbs` than scripting the OS, so it can be a bit confusing :P

Comment: If you remove `.JS` from `%PATHEXT%`, though, then it won't run the local `.js` file **or** the one on the `%PATH%`. No good solution, seems.

Comment: @hBy2Py I didn’t say to remove it. ;) Though I don’t see much use in having it in `%PATHEXT%` if you don’t have `.js` files associated with something that *runs* them like `WScript` or `CScript` or whatever.

Comment: Indeed -- seems like a terrific security hole, if someone can plant a nefarious `.js` on your system and execute it.

Comment: @hBy2Py if an attacker has enough access to plant a file on your system and execute it, you're already screwed, no matter the file extension or the value of the `%PATHEXT%` environment variable.

Comment: @zakinster: On a Unix system you can safely `mkdir foo; cd foo; unzip ../untrusted.zip` and poke around with `ls` (like DOS `dir`) or whatever without worrying that the zip file contained a malicious `ls` executable.  (Unless you made the huge mistake of putting `.` (the current directory) in your `$PATH`, especially as the first component.)  i.e. you can `cd` anywhere you want and safely run commands without executing some file you didn't want to.  With Windows, you have to be careful of files that are just sitting there; it's harder not to accidentally run them when you never planned to.

Comment: @Peter So the take away then is to use the over 10 year old shell built into your OS and not the 25+ year old one that has tons of crusty backwards compatibility built-in. (also note that `dir` is a pretty bad example since that one's a built-in command as it is in (most?) `bash`es)

Comment: @Voo: Are you talking about the graphical shell?  I don't use Windows any more than I can help.  Is PowerShell built in?  I've heard of it but never used it.  (And BTW, no, `ls` is not a built-in in most Unix shells, and definitely not bash.  Neither is `dir`, although my system has a `/bin/dir` which is almost the same as `/bin/ls`, also from GNU coreutils)

Comment: @Peter Right, thought of `echo`, in cmd `dir` is built-in in any case so you can always safely use that one to check for malicious files. Anyhow complaining about deficits in a decades old, deprecated product that's only included for backwards compatibility is a bit unfair. PowerShell doesn't search the current directory for executables either.

Comment: @Voo: oh good, I hadn't realized `cmd` was deprecated.  That's excellent, because it's horrible.  Total garbage to use / program compared to bash.  But it's still the default shell for recovery mode / safe mode.  Is it still accessible by default via right-click or through the start menu?  IIRC I always hit windows-R and type `cmd` when I want a shell on a Windows box without cygwin on mingw, so I don't know if it's at all fair to say that Windows still promotes `cmd` as the go-to / default command shell or if I'm just invoking it directly out of ancient habits when using an OS I rarely touch.

Comment: @Peter Just type PowerShell and you'll be fine. It's actually an excellent shell (with many influences from various Unix shells, but without the backwards compat cruft that those have accumulated over the years) and provides aliases for many of the most common bash commands out of the box (yes `ls` now works everywhere). cmd is still installed so you can use it and find it in the start menu, but in my install at least shift-rightclick only has a "Open PowerShell here" in explorer. No idea about the recovery mode console though, probably still in there.

Comment: @Voo: thanks, I'll try it next time.  Not quite as quick to type as `bash` or `cmd`, though :/.  (I was also thinking of safe-mode command line, which I assume is still `cmd`, and I think last time I booted the install/recovery DVD the shell option was a cmd window.).  A lot of my Windows experience involves trouble-shooting other people's computers :P

Comment: I don't think cmd is deprecated any more than Notepad is, but both have improved versions(powershell & Notepad++ respectively), & the windows cmd always has `.` at the beginning of the path(rather than as a rarely-used option like on sh).  The behaviour of having `.` first on the path is because the first versions of DOS didn't have a path, & so a command was assumed to be in the current directory if you didn't specify otherwise.  It's still the default because of backwards-compatibility.

Comment: @JustinC.B. Apples and oranges. Notepad++ is not a Microsoft product (and not bundled with Windows, etc.). Naming aside, it's as much (or little) of a replacement for Notepad as Sublime Text or even VSCode are. PowerShell, on the other hand, has first-party support and is increasingly becoming the (bundled) default over the legacy Command Prompt, and much of the new commands introduced over the last few years are PowerShell-only.